# Logistic Regression: Should I include a non-significant variable that notably increases the OR of a significant variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, odds-ratio

I am studying the effect of different pollutants on the probability of a genetic mutation.

My binary logistic regression models are as follows:

**Model 1:**

Dependent variable: genetic mutation (binary variable: Mutation/No Mutation).

Predictor variable: Zinc levels (categorical variable: low, medium, high).

OUTPUT: The OR (EXP(B)) for the highest zinc level (vs. lowest) is **7.07** (1.3-37.7) (p=0.022)

**Model 2:**

Dependent variable: gene mutation (binary variable: Mutation/No Mutation).

Predictor variables:

1. Zinc levels (categorical variable: low, medium, high).
2. Hexaclorobenzene (HCB) levels (categorical variable: low, medium, high).

OUTPUT:

The OR (EXP(B)) for the highest zinc level (vs. lowest) is **14.00** (1.6-125.5)(p=0.018)

The OR (EXP(B)) for HCB is 0.754 (0.35-1.6) p-value (**0.465**)

**NOTE:** The OR for Zinc only behaves the same way when adding other pollutants from the same family as HCB. Hexaclorobenzene alone in a model is a non-significant predictor of the mutation.The biological relationship between these pollutants (Zinc and HCB) is unknown. However, both Zinc and HCB might be independently associated with the mutation. After adjusting for other variables (age,sex,smoking,...) the OR for Zinc only doubles when adding to the model HCB and HCB-related pollutants.

*¿Should I include hexaclorobenzene in the model?*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To give this some perspective, notice that the change in the odds ratio from 7 to 14 just moves it a little bit within a very wide confidence interval that goes up to 38.  Thus--although it's a great question--worrying about the difference is just fussing over incidental noise. Perhaps, then, it's more important to make sure your readers understand just how uncertain either estimate (7 or 14) actually is.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much for your useful response. I was blinded by the absolute increase in the odds ratio and didn't interpret it in the context of a wide confidence interval.